# How are closures supposed to interact with variable binding and resolving?

Tags: variable-binding

I am currently reading the Crafting Interpreter book and I have a question about the [Resolving and Binding chapter](https://craftinginterpreters.com/resolving-and-binding.html)

The author gave this example to illustrate the problem with the implementation at that point in the book.

```
var a = "global";
{
  fun showA() {
    print a;
  }

  showA();
  var a = "block";
  showA();
}
```

The problem being that this prints

```
global
block
```

The argument the author is making is that, once the variable is captured as a closure, it should not be possible to change it, hence the second call to `showA()` should not give a different result from the first call.

The author makes the claim this is an issue to be fixed and the chapter is dedicated to fixing it.

But is this really an issue? If I run the JavaScript version of the code

```
var a = "global";
{
  function showA() {
    console.log(a);
  }

  showA();
  var a = "block";
  showA();
}
```

I get exactly the output the author claims to be wrong. That is:

```
global
block
```

Is the author mistaken to claim this is a bug? Or the author is correct and JavaScript has this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of variables created with the `var` keyword in JS is pretty unintuitive, at least if you're already familiar with how other languages handle scope. You can get some more info on how closures and scope interact in JS on this page --> [Closures - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

In this case, the problem is that a pair of curly brackets doesn't really create a new scope. Therefore, the second declaration of `a` gets converted to an assignment to the first one. In contrast, this code:

```
var a = "global";
function showA() {
  console.log(a);
}
{
  showA();
  let a = "block";
  showA();
}
```

in which I have moved the definition of `showA()` out of the brackets and declared the second `a` with `let` , works "as intended" (i.e. it prints `global` twice).

Importantly, this behaviour isn't a *bug*, as it conforms to the specifications of JavaScript. But it runs counter to how most other languages work (apparently including how Mr. Nystrom intends his language to work in the book you're reading).